# C++ how to load from file array of pointers to objects?

Tags: c++, file, pointers, inheritance, serialization

I have an abstract class Object, which looks like this:

```
class Object
{
public:
    Object();
    virtual void DoSomething() = 0;
    virtual void Save(std::ofstream &file) = 0;
    virtual void Load(std::ifstream &file) = 0;
};
```

I also have classes Ball and TextBox:

```
class Ball : public Object
{
public:
    Ball(int x, int y, int z)
    {
        m_x = x; m_y = y; m_z = z;
    }

    void DoSomething()
    {
        std::cout << m_x << ", " << m_y << ", " << m_z << std::endl;
    }
    void Save(std::ofstream &file)
    {
        file << m_x << " " << m_y << " " << m_z << std::endl;
    }
    void Load(std::ifstream &file)
    {
        file >> m_x >> m_y >> m_z;
    }

private:
    int m_x, m_y, m_z;
};
```

```
class TextBox: public Object
{
public:
    TextBox(std::string message)
    {
        m_message = message;
    }

    void DoSomething()
    {
        std::cout << m_message << std::endl;
    }
    void Save(std::ofstream &file)
    {
        file << m_message << std::endl;
    }
    void Load(std::ifstream &file)
    {
        file >> m_message;
    }

private:
    std::string m_message;
};
```

I have a vector of pointers to theese objects:

```
std::vector<Object*> objects;
objects.push_back(new Ball(1, 2, 3));
objects.push_back(new TextBox("Hello world!"));

for (Object *o : objects) o->DoSomething();
```

I want to save this vector to file. This is very easy. I make something like this:

```
std::ofstream file("foo.txt");
for (Object *o : objects) o->Save(file);
file.close();
```

Now I want to load this. And here is a problem. How I can specify, which object (Ball or TextBox) I supposed to load? I could use some indexes, like that:

```
void Ball::Save(std::ofstream &file)
{
    file << 1 << " " << m_x << " " << m_y << " " << m_z << std::endl;
}
void TextBox::Save(std::ofstream &file)
{
    file << 2 << " " << m_message << std::endl;
}
```

Then, after reading this index, I know, that this is a Ball or a TextBox.

```
int index;
Object *o;

file >> index;
switch (index)
{
case 1: o = new Ball(0, 0, 0); break;
case 2: o = new TextBox(""); break;
}
o->Load(file);
objects.push_back(o);
```

But is there a better way to store this structure? What if I have 100 inheritors of Object? Can I somehow avoid 100-switch case?

Comment: Each time you read an object from a file you have to figure out which object it is, and then construct the appropriate object. No, there is no quick and easy way to do this in C++, you have to do all the work yourself.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Ok, thanks. I just thought there is a magical trick to simplify this thing. Anyway, thanks for reply

Comment: Ok, yes, well, despite the C++ specification growing to about two thousand pages, magic tricks aren't included yet. In general, at some point, in large projects it is not uncommon to have automated scripts that robo-generate C++ code, for handling these kinds of things. Neither it is uncommon to have tools that generate C or C++ code. How old are lex and yacc now? 40 years?

Answer (score 0):

These 'indexes' you came up with are usually called 'metadata'. There are other languages, like java, that support reflection for that purpose but in C++ reflection in still under consideration. For that reason, I would suggest implementing sort of an abstract interface that would return information of the exact class of an object.

Furthermore, I would suggest looking at serialization libraries, that could ease the process of saving and reading data. You can try to start with boost:
https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html

I must admit that I used boost serialization a long time ago, but I remember it was quite easy to use.